# NSIS Change page text fails

Tags: nsis

I want to change the texts in the installer pages like MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TITLE.
But it doesn't work. Can someone please give me a hint?
The standard text is displayed.

```
!include "FileFunc.nsh"
!include "Library.nsh"
!include "UMUI.nsh"
!include "MUI2.nsh"
!include "WordFunc.nsh"

!define MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TITLE  $(MUI_TEXT_WELCOME_INFO_TITLE_INFINGY)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(xyz)` is a LangString, use `${mydefine}` if you used `!define mydefine "Title goes here"`.

You can also use a LangString:

```
!define MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TITLE  "$(MyWelcomeTitle)"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English
LangString MyWelcomeTitle ${LANG_ENGLISH} "Hello World"
```

Comment: Thanx Anders
I used LangStrings
Actualy i wanted to change the texts on the first page where the standard title is "Welcome to the ... Setup Wizard"
I don't want the extra MUI_PAGE_WELCOME. I think i mixed this pages up.

Comment: Yes i mixed it up, what i want to change is
UMUI_TEXT_MULTILANGUAGE_TITLE

Comment: That's what i did.
Thank you and have a nice weekend